# Sequence is not hitting in Oracle Application Apex After creating app

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to create a app in oracle apex. I have installed it in my pc(Ubuntu).

I have created a table and a sequence through sql command in apex.
Like

`create table test (
    test_id number primary key,
    test_name varchar2(20) not null
 );`

and sequence like-

`create sequence test_seq start with 1 increment by 1;`

Now adding a single value in my table through sql-comand

`insert into test values(test_seq.nextval, 'Test');`

Okey runnig successfully.[1 row added]

But when i create a app using this table -
[Please check it for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfouy.png)

Okey - Page creation successful but when i try to add data in it then it says -

`ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("WORKSPACE"."TEST"."TEST_ID")`

[Click here to See the attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyNvp.png)

So why this problem occurs?

Comment: looks like sequence and primary key column association missing, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not associated sequence to primary column of your table. Alter your table and then try to add data using app.

```
ALTER TABLE TEST
MODIFY (TEST_ID DEFAULT TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL );
```

Ideally, you would create sequence first and then while creating table, you can define column default as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    TEST_ID NUMBER DEFAULT TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TEST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
 );
```

Comment: Sorry for the type, I have updated code now. Try again and let me know.

Comment: Same Problem, got this -

`ORA-00984: column not allowed here`

[Screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/0ak0Q)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Insert into test
(Test_id,test_name)
Select test_seq.nextval, 'something'
   From dual;
 Commit;
```